# Disable Visual editor for all users

Tags: editor

Is there a way to Disable the visual editor for all users without logging in and setting each user's setting in the admin panel, preferable some way to do it with code in the functions file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way seems to be to use the [Disable Visual Editor Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/disable-visual-editor/).

The plugin also recommends that you remove the `wp-includes/js/tinymce/` directory, but will require maintenance every upgrade.

Answer (score 21):

Not sure if this still works. Preferably, drop this inside your theme's functions.php:

`add_filter( 'user_can_richedit' , '__return_false', 50 );`

Comment: It worked beautifully!

Comment: Same here, worked great, even in the [Pods Framework](http://pods.io) plugin that uses TinyMCE.

Comment: This will change text edit behaviour. For example, without this code, &nbsp; would be kept as it, while with this __return_false &nbsp; will be converted to invisible whitespace in backend text editor.